# How to Load multiple icons faster titanium appcelerator?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

currently i have been working in a project to create chat client support emoticons icons, but i facing a problem that in my titanium appcelerator project i must load > 100 emoticons in a view. The fact that titanium appcelerator load multi images very slow, and i don't know why it happen, can someone suggest me a solution to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

assuming your UI implementation can support it; load a single image that has all ~100 emoticons and add a touchend event listener to the image view. the even returns the x,y coordinate which you can then map to the emoticon that was selected.

```
var self = Ti.UI.createView({backgroundColor: '#666'});

var emoticons = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image: 'http://www.berkeley.edu/news2/2013/04/Finch300.jpg'
});

emoticons.addEventListener('touchend',function(e){
    alert('x: '+e.x+' y: '+e.y);
})
self.add(emoticons);
```